# Why are the strings not being added into the PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

**I am trying to create an array holding the dates of each title.**  However the $dates array is var_dumping int(1) rather than an array. And $dates[0] is NULL.

The csv files follow this formatting: **log_2013_14_04.csv**. The substr is working fine and cropping the date from the file, but why is the information not being added into the array?

```
$files = glob('*.csv');
$dates = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
    $str = substr($files[$i],-14, -4);
    $dates = array_push($dates, $str);
}
var_dump($dates);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's either

```
array_push($dates, $str);
```

or

```
$dates[] = $str;
```

Not

```
$dates = array_push($dates, $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `array_push` returns new length of array not an array himself.

Comment: Great, thanks! I misunderstood array_push then.  I'm used to actionscript. How do I add a variable to the end of an array? I tried `$dates = $str;` but then $dates is a string.